# Boot strapping AWS auto scale instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

We are discussing at a client how to boot strap auto scale AWS instances. Essentially, a instance comes up with hardly anything on it. It has a generic startup script that asks somewhere "what am I supposed to do next?"

I'm thinking we can use amazon tags, and have the instance itself ask AWS using awscli tool set to find out it's role. This could give puppet info, environment info (dev/stage/prod for example) and so on. This should be doable with just the DescribeTags privilege. I'm facing resistance however.

I am looking for suggestions on how a fresh AWS instance can find out about it's own purpose, whether from AWS or perhaps from a service broker of some sort.

Comment: Not going to make this an answer (unless it actually is the answer for you), but we tag and have the instance pull an RPM (or deb) with everything you need.

Comment: In your implementation, how does the VM find out about it's own tags and does this suggest the name of the RPM it installs?

Comment: write a startup script that queries the api and installs the appropriate package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 instances offer a feature called [User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) meant to solve this problem. User Data executes a shell script to perform provisioning functions on new instances. A typical pattern is to use the User Data to download or clone a configuration management source repository, such as Chef, Puppet, or Ansible, and run it locally on the box to perform more complete provisioning.

As @e-j-brennan states, it's also common to prebundle an AMI that has already been provisioned. This approach is faster since no provisioning needs to happen at boot time, but is perhaps less flexible since the instance isn't customized.

You may also be interested in [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html), which exposes some data such as network details and tags via a URL path accessible only to the instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

An instance doesn't have to come up with 'hardly anything on it' though. You can/should build your own custom AMI (Amazon machine image), with any and all software you need to have running on it, and when you need to auto-scale an instance, you boot it from the AMI you previously created and saved.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-create-custom-ami.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use AWS Beanstalk for creating specific instances, this makes it easier since it will create the AutoScaling groups and Launch Configurations (Bootup code) which you can edit later. Also you only pay for EC2 instances and you can manage most of the things from Beanstalk console.